# Python - How display, and update value (printed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scroll, interface, output

I have a python script which receives values in realtime. In a green circle that value need to update in real time. In pink cirkle are line from txt file. I have problem becouse actually i use "os.system("cls")" and print all this but that looks bad when value refresh "fastest", i think you know what's happening.
I want "design interface" it will not update but only value who i want to "refresh". Someone have idea?

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/afTDf.png

Comment: Have a look at [Rich is a Python library for rich text and beautiful formatting in the terminal](https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich)

Comment: It's cool but, i must have 2 table to up (interface) and bottom :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps curses. You will need `pip install windows-curses`. The following snippet is a piece of what I imagine may suit.

```py
import curses
import time
import random

sometext = "User1: xyz\nUser3: xyz\nUser4: xyz\nUser5: xyz\nUser6: xyz\n"

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr(6, 0, sometext)
    for _ in range(0, 10):
        stdscr.addstr(2, 2, f"Value: {random.random() * 10: .0f}")
        stdscr.addstr(3, 2, f"Value2: {random.random() * 100: .0f}")
        stdscr.addstr(4, 2, f"Value3: {random.random() * 1000: .0f}")
        stdscr.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.5)

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: But how i can print, 4 lines (live) and 20 lines from txt?

Comment: Edited to illustrate. This is about as far as I can go based on my reading of your description.